# How to expose a property at different level of schema in Hot Chocolate

Tags: .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I am working on converting a shodily designed REST API into a smooth GraphQL API with Entity Framework Core and Hot Chocolate.

I am currently exposing my entire database via `UseProjection`.
My database contains a table `Foo` with a foreign key to table `Bar` which has property `Baz`.

This is currently exposed as:

```
Foo {
  Bar {
    Baz
  }
}
```

In my case, `Foo` and `Bar` have a 1:1 relationship.
I would like to hide `Bar` from the API, and expose the following:

```
Foo {
  Baz
}
```

I have added the following in `FooType.cs`:

```
descriptor
    .Field("Baz")
    .Resolve(ctx => ctx.Parent<Foo>().Bar?.Baz);
```

If I run a query that accesses `Baz` *at both levels* then GQL correctly returns `Baz` at both levels. However, if I omit the 3-level request, then the SQL call never pulls `Baz` from the database, and therefore the 2-level request returns `null`.

The [Hot Chocolate docs](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/fetching-data/projections#always-project-fields) say you can fix this problem by adding:

```
descriptor
    .Field(Foo => Foo.Bar)
    .IsProjected(true);
```

However, when I run a query with this code in place, I receive an error `A composite type always needs to specify a selection set`. So I not only need to tell Hot Chocolate to project `Bar`, but also specify a set of fields in `Bar`? How do I do that?

P.S. I can get around the above error by explicitly adding fields to the query, but I don't want to pollute my query.

P.P.S I can also do it by resolving `Foo.Bar` with a DataLoader, but since I have ~1k `Foo`s each with a unique `Bar` and unique `Baz`, that would require ~1k database calls. I want to do this in one call.

Hot Chocolate v11, netcore3.1

**EDIT**

`IsProjected(true)` is meant to be used on a property, not a table. The question becomes, how do I project across a table into a property?

Comment: I have the same problem. did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to tell EF to "auto include" your navigation property `Baz`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.navigationbuilder.autoinclude?view=efcore-6.0

Ex:

```
public class BarConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Bar>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Bar> builder)
    {
        builder.Navigation(x => x.Baz).AutoInclude();
    }
}
```